# Namespace/Mymodule/Block/Item.php file code not accessible on frontend after adding through xml

Tags: zend-framework, magento

i am working on a module e.g "**Mymodule**", in which i need to filter the results. i.e. for Partners i created **Partner.php** and for Community i created **Community.php** in

```
Mymodule/Block/Partner.php 
Mymodule/Block/Community.php
```

Now i wanted to access their code in frontend through Mymodule.XML

```
<block type="mymodule/partner" ......................... />
```

but this doesn't work on LIVE SERVER, although it does work on local Wamp server :( ... Any idea ?

Although when i access the default Mymodule.php code in the same and add the code i placed in partner and community file, it does work.

Is there something i am missing ?

Comment: <block type="mymodule/partner" ......................... />

<block type="mymodule/community" ......................... />

<block type="mymodule/mymodule" ......................... />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not strictly sure how your code would ever have worked. But assuming you haven't built a module before, you'll need a minimum of 3 files.

```
app/etc/modules/Sonassi_Module.xml
app/code/community/Sonassi/Module/etc/config.xml
app/code/community/Sonassi/Module/Block/Partner.php
```

In the first file ... `app/etc/modules/Sonassi_Module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Sonassi_Module>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
    </Sonassi_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

In the second file ... `app/code/community/Sonassi/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Sonassi_Module>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Sonassi_Module>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <module>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Sonassi_Module</module>
          <frontName>module</frontName>
        </args>
      </module>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <module>
        <class>Sonassi_Module_Block</class>
      </module>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

In the third file ... `app/code/community/Sonassi/Module/Block/Partner.php`

```
class Sonassi_Module_Block_Partner extends Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

Then finally, you can then use

```
<block type="module/partner" ......................... />
```

Comment: If you define the code pool as local, you have to use the `local` folder in the path. Additionally, you do not need the whole `frontend` tag in the config.xml...

Comment: @sonassi i am using moduleCreator, so all my files are added, like config.xml, system.xml, mymodule.xml and all working files hierarchy but still i am not able to get what i want to on live.

Comment: @atif Well, you have changed your code and question since I've posted, so this makes it difficult. I have provided working code, so all I can suggest is using what I put and flushing your caches.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to define the blocks in your module's config.xml:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Namespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Second, you have to use the right block type in your layout XML:

```
<block type="mymodule/partner" ......................... />
```

You must not write ".php" in the block type. Note, that the term "**mymodule**" has to be the same in the config xml as well as in the block type.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @simon for the reply. And sorry for the lack of code and error, actually i  placed only a piece of code, further more i have already define the blocks in the config.xml.
and also in module i have written partner not partner.php in xml. Have edited the question